# How can we do insert into mdb nodejs from linux/macos?

Tags: node.js, linux, ms-access

I try to used node-adodb but it didnt work. It works on Windows, but not on MacOS, Linux. Please help.

> npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
>
> npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for node-adodb@5.0.3: wanted
> {"os":"win32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"})
>
> npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    win32
>
> npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined
>
> npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   darwin
>
> npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: arm64

Comment: which version of nodejs did you install on the linux server? Same for Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 0):

As the error points out, `node-adodb` **only** works on windows, and only if `Microsoft Access Database Engine` is installed.